# You're attempting to animate multiple children within AnimatePresence, but its exitBeforeEnter prop is set to true

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

#### Error on Browser Console

```
You're attempting to animate multiple children within AnimatePresence,
but its exitBeforeEnter prop is set to true. This will lead to odd visual behaviour.
```

[image: Error Image]

#### App.js (Enclosed within BrowserRouter)

```js
<Switch>
       <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
          <Route key="1"  exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route key="2"  exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
          <Route key="3"  exact path="/articles" component={Articles}/>
       </AnimatePresence>
 </Switch>
```

#### Home.js/Articles.js

```js
const Home = props =>{
  return(
    <motion.h1 initial={{x:-100}} animate={{x:0}} exit={{x:-100}}>Home/Articles</motion.h1>
  )
}

export default Articles
```

Can anyone explain what is causing the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As docs says about `exitBeforeEnter`:

> If set to true, AnimatePresence will only render **one component** at a time. The exiting component will finished its exit animation before the entering component is rendered.

So with this prop enabled you want it the other way, wrap `Switch` with `AnimatePresence`

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path="/articles" component={Articles}/>
  </Switch>
</AnimatePresence>
```

Note that you also need to pass `key` for `Switch`